# Getting the data in Flex pop up window at run time

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating a project in Flex.

I have a main page from which i open a popup window on button click. i this pop up window to display my data which i am getting from my Http request in my response() as rawdata. I did broke this data into array.

I can display the data everytime i close the popup window and open it again. But to do it at run time -- is the problem. I did tried to call the request.sent() again and again in a for loop, and it works, but it tends to send alot of http request, that is not good i believe.

can anyone please help me wiht this Flex problem.

Best
Zeeshan

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use a framework like PureMVC or Cairngorm for separation of model and view. You want some non-UI actionscript code to be managing the requests and (if necessary) caching of the data. This way you can display the data in any view you like. Difficult to illustrate in a simple response, but check out wikipedia for the basics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller

If opening a popup requires the data to be refreshed, then you issue a data-refresh command and wait for the response. If you have the data, and it's not stale, you just need to display it and not make needless HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you send one request you should get one response

If you want to re-display that response over and over to the user - I would suggest using a Timer Task...Have the task run every so many milliseconds and do an Alert.Display(data)

Comment: you are suggesting to send a http request again and again to the server??

Comment: i saw some in for flex examples, "run time dashboard" i want to make something like that.. but i did not understand how that thing is working, and how can i have that kind of functionality in  my code.